# NodeJS/HTML "localhost refused to connect" for Grafana

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cors, grafana

I'm trying to make a simple web app that upon clicking, it will redirect me to Grafana.
However, it says localhost refused to connect.

My code is as follows:

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const helmet = require("helmet");
const app = express();
app.use(helmet.frameguard({ action: "SAMEORIGIN" }));


// Serve static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const indexPath = path.join(__dirname, 'index.html');
  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(indexPath);
  readStream.pipe(res);
});

const PORT = 8000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

index.html

```
html code here
.
.
.
.
.
<div class="section" onclick="navigateTo('http://localhost:3000')">Dashboard</div>
<div class="iframe-container">
      <iframe id="my-iframe" src=""></iframe>
</div>
<script>
    function navigateTo(url) {
      document.getElementById('my-iframe').src = url;
    }
</script>
```

and when I run node app.js and launch localhost:8000 on Chrome/Firefox, clicking on the 'Dashboard' shows my "localhost refused to connect".

There are several issues on these, and I've tried setting X-frame to SAMEORIGIN, adding php file, etc.. but they still don't work.

Are there any other fixes to this I may have missed?

Thank you.